# Why does Tocharian seem to have an uncanny relation with English?

Tags: tocharian

Tocharian is an interesting language, and it seems to have some relations to English in we Here is why I am saying this:

- It is a centum language and the languages in that area are usually satem.
- Some of the words, such as son and we, are cognates while the Latin word is not.

Though we may not have that many Tocharian words, I feel that this is is kind of bizarre and deserves an answer. Also, if there are words, where are there some?

Comment: English is spoken in India, which is a very satem language area. What exactly is "bizarre" about Tocharian? E.g. do you think that Tocharian is closer to English than Gothic is?

Comment: Since the last Tocharian speaker died before there were any English speakers at all, one can't say it has any connection to English, except that both are Indo-European. If some words resemble one another, that's to be expected from languages that are related. Parallel evolution is common. But to prove a connection more specific, one must present evidence of widespread sound changes. Any pair of languages can come up with a dozen pairs of seeming cognates, strictly by coincidence, so you need a **lot** of evidence and some history to believe it.

Comment: What you mention doesn't sound anything like an "uncanny relation". It might have been a relatively unique centum isolate among satem languages, but that doesn't make it any closer to English than it makes to all the other centum languages... and a couple of word correspondences certainly doesn't change that.

Comment: That is not what i meant. I meant germanic languages in general. You have a point.

Answer (score 2):

The standard etymology for Latin *filius* (and *filia*) is from IE **dʰeh₁(y)*- "suck". Oscan retains *puklu* likewise South Picene *puqloh*, from **putlo*, cf. Sanskrit *putra*, so this is not an Italic change, it is Latin. Possibly the proto-Italics got tired of the word **suh₁nús* but could not decide on a better word until later.
Celtic also replaced **suh₁nús* with **makkʷ*. There is nothing at all special in Tocharian or Germanic. There is something about Latin: they replaced the presumed earlier word for "son", just as Modern English got a new word "dog".

Comment: That is probably a good example. So is (probably) Anatolian in a different way. Anatolian is thought to be the first one.

Comment: @NumberFile Anatolian was the earliest to split off, and also the earliest to be recorded in writing, but those two facts aren't necessarily connected (it's just a coincidence that Anatolian is "first" in both ways).

Answer (score -2):

If two languages show features that a third one has not, the most likely assumption is that the third one lost features.

It is assumed that Tocharian split off early (why?), following which it's clear that Latin lost something.

As for *son*, if it compares to *senex*, *senior*, *senorita*, then a sense "my oldest" should be considered. G *Alter*, *altes Haus* is slang like E *bro* (or *daddyo*?), in contrast to *Junge* "young'un, small one; boy, son" for one. If I'm correct, we see that Latin has not lost the root. But that's *phonetically difficult*, as they say, and other interpretations abound that are probably not half wrong.

Comment: The *-nu-* in *suh₁nús is a derivational suffix, not part of the root: cf. Greek υἱός, from the same root *suH- but with a different suffix.